# tracert results not matching routing table (route print)

Tags: windows, networking, routing, traceroute, routing-table

Why would `tracert 10.0.0.1` produce the following results:

```
Tracing route to 10.0.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Indicating that it's using `192.168.0.1` as a next hop when the routing table is as follows:

`route print`:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.2     25
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    286
         10.0.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    286
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
      192.168.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    286
===========================================================================
```

Shouldn't it be using the `10.0.0.2` interface due to this line being the most specific?

```
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    286
```

Edit:

Sometimes I also get `Reply from 10.0.0.2: Destination host unreachable.` followed by `Request timed out.` on `ping`.  Perhaps it thinks it's a bad route and blacklists it (falling back on the default route?)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your topology, but it would seem that whatever is there at 192.168.0.1 knows how to get to 10.0.0.1 and it's also connected to your 10.0.0.2 interface. The key to understand this is that tracert lines list the source address that the intermediate node uses to reach the original source, and not the original intermediate destination.
(It is the source of an ICMP message)

Thus, if 192.168.0.1 has a route to 10.0.0.2 via 192.168.0.2, that (192.168.0.1) will be the source of the ICMP and what you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the metric of the correct route < metric of default route. Mostly you need to make manual metric instead of automatic metric in the interface settings.